# getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer fabric-dev-peer1-org1. Status FAILURE, details: channel 'mychannel' not found

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Getting the following exception when tried to startup fabric gateway application client.

> org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer fabric-dev-peer1-org1.  Status FAILURE, details: channel 'mychannel' not found*

Client was able to connect fine. But after restarting peer containers, application client failed to connect. Below is the error. However, I can see mychannel.block in peer1 at this location `/tmp/org1/peer1/configtx`
I see this files at the above folder - channel.tx, mychannel.block, peerUpdate.tx

And with regards to certs of this peer, I have them on persistant volume, hence don't think I need to register the peer after restart as it would use the old ones.

Below is the error trace and it fails while executing this code
 `val network: Network = gateway.getNetwork(channelName)`

```
2020-10-15 13:53:46.430 ERROR 61897 --- [  restartedMain] org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel       : getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer fabric-dev-peer1-org1.  Status FAILURE, details: channel 'mychannel' not found

org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock for mychannel failed with peer fabric-dev-peer1-org1.  Status FAILURE, details: channel 'mychannel' not found
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigBlock(Channel.java:952) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.2.2.jar:na]
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigBlock(Channel.java:907) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.2.2.jar:na]
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:1964) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.2.2.jar:na]
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.loadCACertificates(Channel.java:1801) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.2.2.jar:na]
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:1222) ~[fabric-sdk-java-2.2.2.jar:na]
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.NetworkImpl.initializeChannel(NetworkImpl.java:59) ~[fabric-gateway-java-2.2.0.jar:na]
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.NetworkImpl.<init>(NetworkImpl.java:50) ~[fabric-gateway-java-2.2.0.jar:na]
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.GatewayImpl.getNetwork(GatewayImpl.java:252) ~[fabric-gateway-java-2.2.0.jar:na]
        at com.mylab.myapi.blockchainservice.fabric.ConsentGateway.<init>(ConsentGateway.kt:42) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Constructor.call(CallerImpl.kt:41) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.3.30.jar:1.3.30-release-171 (1.3.30)]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:106) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.3.30.jar:1.3.30-release-171 (1.3.30)]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflect_api(KCallableImpl.kt:152) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.3.30.jar:1.3.30-release-171 (1.3.30)]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:110) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.3.30.jar:1.3.30-release-171 (1.3.30)]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils$KotlinDelegate.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:308) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:293) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at com.mylab.myapi.blockchainservice.BlockchainserviceApplicationKt.main(BlockchainserviceApplication.kt:14) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]

2020-10-15 13:53:46.431  WARN 61897 --- [  restartedMain] org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel       : Channel mychannel could not load peer CA certificates from any peers.
2020-10-15 13:53:46.566  INFO 61897 --- [  restartedMain] org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel       : Channel Channel{id: 1, name: mychannel} eventThread started shutdown: false  thread: null
```

Anybody knows why? Highly appreciate any advice on this!

Answer (score 0):

I realised after upgrading fabric image from hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.0 to hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2.
Although, I could see channel related bock mychannel.block at the expected location. However, some how it is not being considered. Hence, I recreated the channel and joined the peers to that channel and then installed the chaincode.

After that my client application was able to connect to the peer with out any issues.

Not sure if this is the right approach, but fixed this problem.